# LibreOffice placeholder fields documentation

Tags: libreoffice, documentation, programming, macro

I have to modify a LibreOffice template with a number of conditional statements.

I managed to figure out one can add such statements through `Insert > Fields > More fields`, tab `Functions`, type `Placeholders` and format `Text` (as of LibreOffice 5.0.6.2), but I can't seem to find the list of available functions.

Where do I find some documentation for this language ?

Comment: FWIW, I am specifically trying to figure out if `<ELSE>`, `NOT` and `LENGTH(ARRAY)` do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this is not a LibreOffice standard macro language, but **[relatorio](http://relatorio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)**, a subset of **[Genshi](https://genshi.edgewall.org/)** (the question was in the context of **[tryton](http://doc.tryton.org/2.2/trytond/doc/topics/reports/index.html)**).

According to the first link, supported directives from Genshi are :

- `py:for` ;
- `py:if` ;
- `py:choose` ;
- `py:when` ;
- `py:otherwise` ;
- `py:with`.

It seems that inside a `TEST=""` statement, standard python syntax is allowed (i.e. in the case I was interested in, see comment above, `len(array)`).